# How to attribute the right encoding for PointValuePlot

Tags: parameters

in the following program

```
    PointValuePlot[{{1, 1} -> {"x", 0.2, 1}, {2, 2} -> {"y", 0.8, 2}, {3,3} -> {"z", 0.2, 3}}
 , {1 -> "Label", 2 -> "Color", 3 -> "Shape"}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow" ]
```

I do expect that the first data is a label, the second represented by a color and the third  by a shape. However, the third value is represented by a color AND a different shape while the second information is not shown at all. As result, all the nodes are colored differently while the first and third points have the same value, confirming that the result is not what we expect by the specification of the encoding.

How can I transform this program such that the second information is really described by a color and not the third ?
Thank you